create array of structs, fill with struct vars(consist of 4 strings which are inputed by user), print those vars out
I'm trying to create a function that allows to create some records (a part of my data base proj) that consist of 4 strings. Than this function has to print those records out
But it doesn't print anything out (there are no errors)
below are the files: main.c just calls different functions, organs.c stores all the functions, organs.h has struct type
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "organs.h"

int main(){

    initMenu();
    int chosenOption = chooseOption(); //chosen option

    //working with chosen option
    switch (chosenOption){
        case 1:
            userKeyboardInput();
            break;
            //other cases not done yet
    }

}

organs.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "organs.h"

struct nn records[9];

void initMenu(){
    printf(" 1 - Input\n 2 - Output\n 3 - Add record\n 4 - Search\n 5 - Deleting\n 6 - Sort\n 7 - Exit\n");
}
int chooseOption(){
    printf("Choose option form 1 to 7:\n");
    int chosenOption;
    scanf("%d", &chosenOption);
    return chosenOption;
}

void userKeyboardInput(){
    printf("How many records do yo wish to make?\n");
    int noOfRecords;
    scanf("%d", &noOfRecords);
    int counter = 1;
    for(int x = 0; x < noOfRecords; x++){
        printf("%d record\n", counter);
        struct nn newRecord;
        for(int paramNO = 0; paramNO < 4; paramNO++){
            char symbol;
            char param[20];
            int i = 0;


            while(scanf("%c",&symbol) > 0 && (symbol!='\n' || i < 20)){
                param[i] = symbol;
                i++;
            }
            if(paramNO == 0){
                strcpy(newRecord.param1, param);
            }
            if(paramNO == 1){
                strcpy(newRecord.param2, param);
            }
            if(paramNO == 2){
                strcpy(newRecord.param3, param);
            }
            if(paramNO == 3){
                strcpy(newRecord.param4, param);
            }
        }
        records[x] = newRecord;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < noOfRecords; x++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printf("%c", records[x].param1[i]);
        }
        printf ("  ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printf("%c", records[x].param2[i]);
        }
        printf ("  ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printf("%c", records[x].param3[i]);
        }
        printf ("  ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printf("%c", records[x].param4[i]);
        }
        printf ("  ");
    }
}

organs.h
#ifndef UNTITLED2_ORGANS_H
#define UNTITLED2_ORGANS_H

struct nn{
    char param1[20];
    char param2[20];
    char param3[20];
    char param4[20];
};
void initMenu();
int chooseOption();
void userKeyboardInput();

#endif //UNTITLED2_ORGANS_H


I'm not sure why you decided to take input character by character instead of using fgets or similar to read the whole string at once. Because it looks like you aren't adding a null terminator anywhere with param[i] = symbol;. And if there's no null terminator, there's no string and the array can't get passed to strcpy. There might be other bugs as well.

If the strings were null terminated then the printf("%c", records[x].param1[i]); and those for loops could be replaced with a single puts.

You could avoid copying strings entirely if you scanned into the targets directly: char* param; switch(paramNo) { case ... : param = newRecord.paramX; } while(scanf("%c", param) >0 && *param != '\n' { ++param; } – sole difference would be that now the new-line is included as well, but you can easily overwrite after the loop: *param = 0;. Note, that it is still possible to produce buffer overflow as you never check how many characters have actually been entered!

If your struct had arrays of arrays you could have simpler code by iterating over the outer array. Still you could create an array of pointers and iterate over that one: char* params[] = { newRecord.param1, newRecord.param2, newRecord.param3, newRecord.param4 }; for(char **b = params, **e = params + sizeof(params)/sizeof(*params); b != e; ++b) { /* scan into *b */ }

Not considering previous loop advice: If you select between some options upon a single variable a switch-statement (like the one I silently introduced in a previous comment) is more suitable (and allows compiler optimisations like jump tables) – and even if you opt against or have a set on conditions switch is not applicable on, if you have a long chain of if checks where only one of can be true anyway then you are better off applying else: if(c1) { } else if(c2) { } else { /* default case */ } – this avoids needless further checking once one of the conditions has already been met.

You do have a logic error, as pointed out by your one answer so far.  It is conceivable that this explains your actual issue if you have left out important details, such as that the program also doesn't terminate.  Your [mre] would be completed by providing an example input and clarifying the termination question.

As it stands, your database (ie array) could be replaced by an in-place input echo-er. What are the requirements, exactly?

while(scanf("%c",&symbol) > 0 && (symbol!='\n' || i < 20))
{
    param[i] = symbol;
    i++
}

In the case of || logic, if the first one is true he don't check the other's one's.
So the only wait to stop your loop is :

having a EOF character.
having a string with a len > 20 and a '\n' after the 20 first's
character's.

And if I put a string a string > 20 I corrupt the stack, that don't sound really good.

You are right that the logic is incorrect, but this does not seem to answer the question posed.

... or maybe it does, but that's not clear from the question.

There are many problems with your code.
You can adjust it and keep writing this way --- and it is a very common one -- but it is not a good one. It seems it is the way people and book teach this things :(
about the code

Your database project may not need to terminate the param things with 0, or even specify otherwise. But strings are so terminated in C for a reason, and at least in testing you should do it
from your userKeyboardInput:

(symbol != '\n' || i < 20))

This is wrong. If symbol is not newline the code will not test for i<20 and will go on forever, if the code does not crash for segmentation fault. You could use
              (scanf("%c", &symbol) > 0) &&
              (symbol != '\n') &&
              (i < 20)

still not good but at least not wrong.

the code prints blindly the 1st 10 char, but the user could have entered just 2. Or 19. OR 1900 since there is a bug. If your program did not crashed, then you will go with no way of knowing how many symbols are in each block.

struct nn {
  char param1[20];
  char param2[20];
  char param3[20];
  char param4[20];
};

nn? Not a great name. But the worst is that in organs.c you have
    struct nn records[9];

So records is a global thing. This is really bad. And it need to be hunted for in organs.c and not next to the declararion for nn in organs.h. Why?
This is also a bad idea:
void initMenu() {
    printf(" 1 - Input\n 2 - Output\n 3 - Add record\n 4 - Search\n 5 - Deleting\n 6 - Sort\n 7 - Exit\n");
}
int chooseOption() {
    printf("Choose option form 1 to 7:\n");
    int chosenOption;
    scanf("%d", &chosenOption);
    return chosenOption;
}

`Would not be easier just to write
    int menu()

and return the option?
Also for the printf prefer
    printf("\
    1 - Input\n\
    2 - Output\n\
    3 - Add record\n\
    4 - Search\n\
    5 - Deleting\n\
    6 - Sort\n\
    7 - Exit\n");

because it is much more easier to align and to visualize such menu thing.
write aroud your data. Encapsulation
Your data is an array of structs. Where is it? Spread around the code in two files. And for a single use, since it is global to the code.
But as always it is only a container. Encapsulation is a powerful thing.
Consider
#define MAX_RECORDS 9

typedef struct
{
    char param1[20];
    char param2[20];
    char param3[20];
    char param4[20];
} Block;

typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;
    size_t size;
    Block blk[MAX_RECORDS];
} Record;

int menu();
// insert 'N' records into container 'R' 
int factory(size_t N, Record* R);

This is the same thing, but now you can have many records, no global thing, and is far more solid and easier to test. factory is a factory function, much more convenient than using userKeyboardInput and for each test force the user to type in all the block letter by letter.
EXAMPLE
Using this idea, main.c as
#include <stdio.h>
#include "organs1.h"

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int res = 0;
    Record one;
    one.limit = MAX_RECORDS;
    one.size = 0;

    rcd_show(&one, "\n[still empty]    ");

    res = rcd_factory(4, &one);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nrcd_factory returned %d\n", res);
    rcd_show(&one, "\n[4 inserted]    ");

    res = rcd_factory(400, &one);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nrcd_factory returned %d\n", res);
    rcd_show(&one, "\n[400 inserted?]    ");
    return 0;
}

This calls rcd_show passing the address of some Record:

at first it is empty
then calls res = rcd_factory(4, &one); to insert 4 records
then calls res = rcd_factory(400, &one);. Since MAX_RECORDS is 6 this is the total inserted,  and rcd_factory returns -2

output

[still empty]    0/6 records in set


rcd_factory returned 0

[4 inserted]    4/6 records in set

    [1/4]
        [01]  R00000000 Param 1
        [02]  R00000000 Param 2
        [03]  R00000000 Param 3
        [04]  R00000000 Param 4
    [2/4]
        [01]  R00000001 Param 1
        [02]  R00000001 Param 2
        [03]  R00000001 Param 3
        [04]  R00000001 Param 4
    [3/4]
        [01]  R00000002 Param 1
        [02]  R00000002 Param 2
        [03]  R00000002 Param 3
        [04]  R00000002 Param 4
    [4/4]
        [01]  R00000003 Param 1
        [02]  R00000003 Param 2
        [03]  R00000003 Param 3
        [04]  R00000003 Param 4

rcd_factory returned -2

[400 inserted?]    6/6 records in set

    [1/6]
        [01]  R00000000 Param 1
        [02]  R00000000 Param 2
        [03]  R00000000 Param 3
        [04]  R00000000 Param 4
    [2/6]
        [01]  R00000001 Param 1
        [02]  R00000001 Param 2
        [03]  R00000001 Param 3
        [04]  R00000001 Param 4
    [3/6]
        [01]  R00000002 Param 1
        [02]  R00000002 Param 2
        [03]  R00000002 Param 3
        [04]  R00000002 Param 4
    [4/6]
        [01]  R00000003 Param 1
        [02]  R00000003 Param 2
        [03]  R00000003 Param 3
        [04]  R00000003 Param 4
    [5/6]
        [01]  R00000004 Param 1
        [02]  R00000004 Param 2
        [03]  R00000004 Param 3
        [04]  R00000004 Param 4
    [6/6]
        [01]  R00000005 Param 1
        [02]  R00000005 Param 2
        [03]  R00000005 Param 3
        [04]  R00000005 Param 4


organs1.h
#ifndef UNTITLED2_ORGANS1_H
#define UNTITLED2_ORGANS1_H

#define MAX_RECORDS 6

typedef struct
{
    char param1[20];
    char param2[20];
    char param3[20];
    char param4[20];
} Block;

typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;
    size_t size;
    Block blk[MAX_RECORDS];
} Record;

int menu();
// insert 'N' records into container 'R' 
int rcd_factory(size_t N, Record* R);
int rcd_show(Record*, const char*);

#endif 

organs1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "organs1.h"

int menu()
{
    return 0;
}

int rcd_factory(size_t N, Record* rcd)
{
    char name[20] = {0};
    if (rcd == NULL) return -1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {   // R12345678 Param X"
        if (rcd->size == rcd->limit) return -2;
        sprintf(name, "R%08llu Param 1", rcd->size);
        strcpy(rcd->blk[rcd->size].param1, name);
        name[16] = '2';
        strcpy(rcd->blk[rcd->size].param2, name);
        name[16] = '3';
        strcpy(rcd->blk[rcd->size].param3, name);
        name[16] = '4';
        strcpy(rcd->blk[rcd->size].param4, name);
        rcd->size += 1;
    }
    return 0;
};

int rcd_show(Record* rcd, const char* msg)
{
    if (rcd == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL)
        printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%llu/%llu records in set\n\n", rcd->size, rcd->limit);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rcd->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("\
    [%llu/%llu]\n\
        [%02d]  %s\n\
        [%02d]  %s\n\
        [%02d]  %s\n\
        [%02d]  %s\n",
            1+i,rcd->size,
            1, rcd->blk[i].param1,
            2, rcd->blk[i].param2,
            3, rcd->blk[i].param3,
            4, rcd->blk[i].param4);
    };
    return 0;
};


That's like the most detailed review & fix of my code. Honestly I didn't expect it to be so good, receive my gratitude

This is a very good question, in a broad sense: the notion of a container of structs; the need to use a factory function  to produce data to generate database records; the possible  use of encapsulation_  of the database records; the convenience of using null-terminated strings. I think it is good to have an example like this one in SO, with code and output and some discussion. Cheers.
